# Playing unity from a button in an Android Studio application?

Tags: android-studio, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am building an app with a few buttons.

One of those buttons is supposed to open a unity application I created that includes Vuforia.

After exporting unity-vuforia and turning it into an AAR file, I can't seem to create a new module in Android Studio with it as a library.

It says that the roots are wrong.

I'm new to Android development and would like to know how to integrate a unity-vuforia app to a button.

When the button is clicked the unity-vuforia should be opened.

Comment: Hi Daniel, it would be good for other users if you included some stand-alone example code to better illustrated your situation. 
Also, you should read this to get a better response.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thank you Francis, I will do a better question with the guide you provided

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52088003/run-a-piece-of-unity-from-within-a-native-android-app.              Francis